# Detox issues with AppleSimUtils and CircleCI

Tags: ios, circleci, detox

I am trying to setup the detox build for ios in circleci using the macos executor. The issue I had was with applesmiutils. When the app tries to run, it executes the command `applesimutils --list byId='SIM_ID'`. This command if run locally, gives the desired results but causes a failure on CircleCI. The failure is:

```
rror: The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.. See “applesimutils --help” for usage.

Error: Unable to obtain a list of simulators. See “applesimutils --help” for usage.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of debugging and trying different versions of applesimutils, it did not help. Even without the detox commands the `applesimutils --list` command was failing but if we do `sudo applesimutils --list` that was successful.

So, definitely something wrong with the `applesimutils --list`. I downgraded the utils but no use.

The issue was that I was using `NVM` in my CircleCI setup that printed these lines when the `xcrun simctl list devices` command was run by applesimutils:

```
v16.19.1 is already installed.
Now using node v16.19.1 (npm v8.19.3)
```

This caused the data format to change from JSON to a format not recognizable by applesimutils.

I changed the node installation script to `brew install node@16` and everything started working including detox tests!